# How can i get the content of a file if it isn't contain a valid UTF-8

Tags: rust

I need to get the content of a `.jsp`, I have been using `std::fs::read_to_string`:

```rust
if f.file_name() == "entry.jsp" {
    // read_file(f.path().to_str().unwrap());
    println!("{:?}", f.file_name());
    let contents = fs::read_to_string(f.path()).expect("Something went wrong reading the file");
}
```

but I got the following error:

> "stream did not contain valid UTF-8"

I tried with `std::io::BufReader` reading the file line by line but I don't know how i can get the lines as a string.

```rust
fn read_file(path: &str) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open(path)?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    for line in reader.lines() {
        println!("{}", line?);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

How could I get the content as a `String`?

Thanks.

Comment: what is inside your file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings in Rust are required to be UTF-8, so you can't get the *exact* content as a `String`. What you can do is read the file as bytes (with eg. [`read_to_end`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_end)), then convert the bytes to a string with [`from_utf8_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy).

```
if f.file_name() == "entry.jsp" {
    // read_file(f.path().to_str().unwrap());
    println!("{:?}", f.file_name());
    let file = File::open(path)?;
    let mut buf = vec![];
    file.read_to_end (&mut buf)?;
    let contents = String::from_utf8_lossy (&buf);
}
```

Note however that, as the "lossy" part of the name suggests, the string you get will be different from the contents of the file:

> Not all byte slices are valid strings, however: strings are required to be valid UTF-8. During this conversion, `from_utf8_lossy()` will replace any invalid UTF-8 sequences with [`U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/char/constant.REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER.html), which looks like this: �

If you know that your input uses some valid character encoding other than UTF-8, there are other solutions:

- [`from_utf16`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html?search=#method.from_utf16) if your file uses UTF-16 (or UCS-2) encoding.
- The [`encoding_rs`](https://crates.io/crates/encoding_rs) or [`encoding`](https://crates.io/crates/encoding) crates for other character encodings.

Comment: The [encoding_rs](https://crates.io/crates/encoding_rs) crate is more popular than `encoding`.

Comment: @Aloso thanks, added reference to `encoding_rs`